# Composition and circular dependency

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, composition, circular-dependency

- A *Channel* contains *elements* of type E.
- A channel also **has** a *port* that gives access to the elements **in** the channel

It should look something like this:

```
template<
    typename E>
class IOutPort{
public:

    ...

    /**
    *    Takes an element (chosen by the implementation) that is in channel
    *
    *    @return
    *        The element
    */
    virtual E take() = 0;
};

template<
    typename E>
class IChannel {
public:

    ...

    /**
    *    Gives access to the out port of this channel
    *
    *    @return
    *        A smart pointer to the channel's port
    */
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IOutPort<E>> getOutPort() = 0;
};
```

They both need to reference themselves..
In addition:

- The channel impl cannot provide a shared_ptr of itself to the port impl at construction time  (because it is not complete yet)
- If both use strong references they will never be freed
- Some user code may want to store the port's pointer for later use... So at that time the channel must still exist!

Breaking the circle with a weak_ptr may lead to a premature destruction of the channel!

Which is the best pattern to follow, without merging the two interfaces??

**EDIT:**
@Edwin Yes i have already checked the existing discussions...
The answer i'm looking for is more ethical than technical...

Substantially, which are the advantages of composition in a language like C++ that lacks memory management and usability of 'this' at construction time, when the composed object needs to access the composer?

I'm in the idea that the unique solution is to implement the composer and (privately) all the components interfaces in the same class (in order to resolve the component-to-composer communication problem).
And maybe provide specific views of that unique same class to make appear that 'is-a' relation in a 'has-a' relation...
But in such scenario all the composition advantages are lost!

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed yet, but a lot of the topics being asked in the side bar on the right sound awfully similar to what you're asking. Did you check them out first before posting the question?

Answer (score 1):

The question is too abstract and separated from application. What happens when your stuff in the channel changes, who is responsible for propagating through port? Would the application be better served by a stream protocol rather than object-oriented API? How many channels versus how many port-listeners will there be?

Comment: It operates in concurrent environment. When an agent is ready to handle one element it invokes 'take' from the port. Other may do the same thing... But only one element is take out from the port at a time, so
the implementation and the scheduler policy contribute to some form of serialization. The 'channel' abstraction servers the purpose of hiding the semantic of the element insertion:
it could be a constrained-size queue, a prioritized queue (each insertion must carry the information about the priority...), a randezvou between the inserter and the awaiting taker etc...